# JQuery / AJAX - Submit form after ajax resolved

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that I want to validate the data of and then store the values in a $_SESSION variable before the form is submitted.  So far my code returns false if the validation fails, but submits the form before the AJAX has completed.  I'm not sure how to do that bit:

```
$('#c_form').submit(function() {
    if ($("#del_f").val().length == 0) {
        $("#del_f").addClass("alert-danger");
        $("#del_f").focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#del_f").removeClass("alert-danger");
    }
    if ($("#del_s").val().length == 0) {
        $("#del_s").addClass("alert-danger");
        $("#del_s").focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#del_s").removeClass("alert-danger");
    }
    var update_session_delivery = "n=" + $("#del_f").val() + " " + $("#del_s").val();
    var ajax1 = $.ajax({
        url: 'work/update_session_delivery.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: update_session_delivery,
        success: function(result) {}
    });

    $.when(ajax1).done(
        function() {
            //submit the form?
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: The way you've done it it's not possible to do what you want. You need to call `$('#c_form').submit()` in the `success` part of your ajax. BTW, you should use `.done` now instead of `success`. But that would just cause a loop, you can't intercept the submission of the form, delay it until ajax is complete and then continue submitting it. What you need to do is have a button the user has to click outside of the form to trigger the ajax then call the form submit in the `.done` part of the ajax.

Comment: Perfect.  I have no idea why I didn't think of that.  Thanks

Comment: Why you want to do in this way? what is your need?

Answer (score 0):

try e.preventDefault:

```
 $('#c_form').submit(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();//prevent form from submiting
         var form = $(this);
        if ($("#del_f").val().length == 0) {
            $("#del_f").addClass("alert-danger");
            $("#del_f").focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            $("#del_f").removeClass("alert-danger");
        }
        if ($("#del_s").val().length == 0) {
            $("#del_s").addClass("alert-danger");
            $("#del_s").focus();
            return false;
        } else {
            $("#del_s").removeClass("alert-danger");
        }
        var update_session_delivery = "n=" + $("#del_f").val() + " " + $("#del_s").val();
        var ajax1 = $.ajax({
            url: 'work/update_session_delivery.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: update_session_delivery,
            success: function(result) {
                   //aditional logic here
                form.submit();//submit the form after success
             }
        });


    });
```